# How do I send GPS location data (coordinates) from one iPhone to another

Tags: ios, gps, push-notification, location, apple-push-notifications

I am creating a Find-My-Phone like app that alerts the users where there phone is at if it is lost. The problem I am having is sending and receiving location data from one iOS device to another. What is the best approach to handle this situation? Should I use push notifications or background fetch? or is there another method? I do NOT want to use any third-party sites like Parse.com or Quickblox.com.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to use those?

You could consider creating some sort of direct socket connection between the devices, but my guess is that using push somehow is all you would need.

Comment: I don't want to use Parse because I want to host and manage the data myself.

Comment: Why not just use parse (or whatever) for the push? Manage the data however you want.